# How to pass extra arguments to spark.lapply in SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am new to Spark.  I am trying to convert some R code in parallel into SparkR. Is there function similar to clusterExport with Spark? For example, suppose I have the following code, is there a way pass "y" to spark.lapply function?

```
library(SparkR)

a = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5))

fn_a <- function() {
  sparkR.session()
  y = 2
  result = spark.lapply(a, fn_b) # <- pass y here
  sparkR.session.stop()
  print(result)
}

fn_b <- function(x) {
  return(x * y)
}

fn_a()
```

```
#Expected results
2  4  6  8 10
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the same issue. Come to the conclusion that spark.lapply only takes one argument I think?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/R/spark.lapply.html

"func   a function that takes one argument."